# Post request for XML

Tags: iphone

I have a url:

```
http://192.168.0.6:81/coloplast/getFiles.php?id=a:1:{i:0;i:11;}
```

how to post id=a:1:{i:0;i:11;} for this type url,The out put of these url is

```
<data>
  <tbl>
    <id>10</id>
    <file_name>
      http://192.168.0.6:81/coloplast/upload/video/9_3_video.mp4
    </file_name>
  </tbl>
</data>
```